# workflow email alert is using email address from My Email Settings

Tags: workflow, email-alert

I have created one workflow on contract after inserted and everytime edited. It has Email alert action to send email to account owner. The From Email Address is set to "Current User's Email Address". I have another email address in My Email Settings. Now, after contract created or edited, the email is sending with From address from My Email settings. I dont want this email address to use. It should use my email address from my profile. Is it possible? Please help.

Comment: I tried replicating your concern and found the email is sent from My Profile Email address (Advanced User Details page). Can you tell me how have set "My Email Settings."

Comment: @Robi- In My settings->Email->My Email settings, i have defined another email id. Workflow email alert is taking from that email id insted of email is from User detail page.

Comment: I replicated your issue and I guess you are right. I also tried the same with Process Builder and Apex Trigger, but all the time mail is sent from My Email Settings only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will always take from the My email setting whatever email specified. But an improvement on " From address" is in the idea list and its luckily went to the product team review stage.

[Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000JFy2AAG)